# Using dd without sudo

Tags: usb, sudo, chmod, dd, raspberrypi

I would like to allow others to use my computer to write images to SD cards for raspberry pi. For this you need to use `dd if={image} of=/dev/sdX`. I thought about giving the `dd` command `sudo` rights, but then I have the problem that others could override my O/S drive.

The right way would be to `chmod o+w /dev/sdX*` - Since they can use a USB hub, or plug in a SD card reader the output device `/dev/sd`.. is not always the same. Is there a way to dynamically assign write access to others for a range of possible USB devices only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom `udev` rule. This rule would make all USB storage devices world writeable:

```
echo 'KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", MODE="0666"' | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-storage.rules
```

Take a look at ['Writing udev rules'](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) for more infos about that.